# Error in a simple applet

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint

The following code is supposed to print

inside `init()`-- inside `start()`-- inside `paint()`.

But it prints the last part `inside paint()` TWICE! Why is that?

```
public class SampleApplet extends Applet {

String msg;

@Override
public void init(){
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setForeground(Color.yellow);
    msg = "Inside init()-- ";
  }

@Override 
public void start(){
    msg += "Inside start()-- ";
  }

@Override 
public void paint(Graphics g){
    msg += "Inside paint().";
    g.drawString(msg, 10, 30);
  }
}
```

Comment: See this answer for an explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067844/paint-in-java-applet-is-called-twice-for-no-reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from: [Paint()](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1249117):

> the paint() method will be called as many times as necessary. If you
>   put another window over your GUI then the paint() method will be
>   called. If you then minimize that window and make your GUI visible
>   again then the paint() method will be called again. And so on.
>
> So if you have something that is a problem if the paint() method is
>   called more than once, you have done it wrong. Don't do it that way.
>   The paint() method should only redraw its target from existing data,
>   it should never have to do calculations to figure out what to paint.

Comment: So you mean the calculations in `msg += "inside paint()."` caused a problem??

Answer (score 2):

The `paint` method may be called by `update` when the component needs to repaint the content of the component state is invalidated.