# Why JFrame running or executes 2 times?

Tags: java, swing, loops

I have this code on my other JFrame:

```
test2 diagram = new test2(headers,inputSize);
diagram.setVisible(true);
```

This code is what I use to call this JFrame which has a code of:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static ArrayList<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
    static int inputSize;

    public test2 (ArrayList<String> headers, int inputSize)
    {
        initComponents();
        this.headers = headers;
        this.inputSize = inputSize;
    }
    public test2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        int x = 50;
        int y = 60;
        int st1 = 48;

        for(int a=0;a<inputSize;a++)
        {
            System.out.println("a"+a);
            g2.drawString(headers.get(a), st1, 55);
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x, y, x, 450));
            x = x+30;
            st1 = st1+30;
        }
        for(int ctr=0;ctr<2;ctr++)
        {
            System.out.println(ctr);
        }
```

I've changed the paint() to paintComponents(). The problem is it does not executes or viewing the output of the loops which means it does not go to the loop. I use Graphics2D is there other way to create a line?

Comment: Possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067844/paint-in-java-applet-is-called-twice-for-no-reason

Comment: It can call it as many times as it likes, and more.

Comment: Don't override the paint() method of a Frame!!! Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper way to do painting.

Comment: Still won't work. I directly draw lines in a JPanel? Is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

First, the correct method to override is `paintComponent(...)` not `paint(...)`.

Get more information here:
[paint() in java applet is called twice for no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067844/paint-in-java-applet-is-called-twice-for-no-reason)

Comment: I like the answer from the comment link better than this link.

Comment: You are right, the previous link was not as useful as it had only the question.