# Why does the paint method run twice?

Tags: java

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MyApplet extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("This the test.");
        g.drawString("This the test.", 10, 20);
    }
}
```

Output in the console is:

```
This the test.
This the test.
```

Comment: Are there any start, stop methods in class tp? From where maybe you are calling repaint().

Comment: where you are calling this method ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067844/paint-in-java-applet-is-called-twice-for-no-reason

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814289/why-is-my-code-executing-paintcomponentgraphics-page-twice

Comment: run it in a debugger to see what it does. Or to get some traces, try:  new RuntimeException("Not a real exception").printStackTrace();

Comment: I had run this program in the netbeans IDE. consider this as the full program. when I run this program thee first console output is as shown above.every time I minimize and maximize the window the paint method runs.. I understood that thing. But why it is running twice at the first time. I tried to debug but i am not getting anything from it. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 4):

In GUI programming, the `paint()` method will be called as many times as necessary. If you put another window over your GUI then the `paint()` method will be called. If you then minimize that window and make your GUI visible again then the `paint()` method will be called again. And so on.

So if you have something that is a problem if the `paint()` method is called more than once, you have done it wrong. Don't do it that way. The `paint()` method should only redraw its target from existing data, it should never have to do calculations to figure out what to paint.

Answer (score 0):

The paint method is called anytime the Applet needs to be drawn again. It is called when the size changes, the gui goes invisible and visible again or you can call it manually using `repaint()`. Sometimes it's called hundreds of times if nessecary, so this behavior is absolutely fine.